# Keep horizontally scrolling header fixed on top using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to keep a header on top of the page using JavaScript. `position: fixed` cannot be used because the header needs to be scrolling horizontally. Keeping it on top is easy but making it **smooth** is problematic. For some users it's smooth in Chrome but it's laggy on Safari for everyone.

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/bufejapuza/edit?html,css,js,output

How do I keep the header fixed on top so that it won't be janky while scrolling.

*Edit: To get it lagging in Chrome, try toggling the HTML, CSS & JS tabs in JSBin.*

Comment: I see the top bar is static not Junky while scrolling!

Comment: @Smit which browser and OS?

Comment: @Smit please try it on Safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use position fixed and adjust X dynamically, not Y

- Change header `position` to `fixed`
- Adjust the x-pos by JavaScript
- No jank while scrolling vertically

```js
function setLocation() {
  var left = -window.scrollX;  
  header.style.transform = "translateX(" + left + "px)";
}
```

I tested this in Firefox and Safari (both Mac) and it fixed the problem.

[Modified JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xebedokahu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Because it uses position fixed.

Comment: But the other way uses position absolute which makes horizontal scrolling smooth. Why does it not lag horizontally when that doesn't use fixed positioning?

Comment: Your code does not change anything while scrolling horizontally, therefore we don't see any jank. ;-)

Comment: That doesn't explain why switching on which axis we use CSS and JS changes the performance of scrolling.

Comment: You are right. What solves the jank problem is the use of position fixed. As fixed takes care of Y, we need to adjust X, only.